# How to get beacon receive new configuration

Tags: ios, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, estimote, android-ibeacon

I have the estimate beacon and I can change uuid from their iOS app 
but from what i read beacon use BLE tec. and it made to send only advertisement data 
so how does it receive the new configuration.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that iBeacons only advertise data, however vendors, such as Estimote, can support additional BLE functionality to allow functionality such as configuration. This is outside of the iBeacon specification and so each vendor will have their own services and chracteristics for this purpose